# "quoted string not properly terminated" sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sqlplus

Getting an error when I try to insert values using the following statement

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NUM, ITEM_NUM, DATE)
VALUES (’11’,’19’, TO_DATE(’01-JAN-2001’,’DD-MON-YYYY’));
```

> ERROR:
>   ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated

Answer (score 6):

Your question has "smart" quotes in the SQL instead of basic single quotes.  Try this:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT(PRODUCT_NUM, ITEM_NUM, DATE)
    VALUES ('11', '19', DATE '2001-01-01')
```

(I prefer the `date` keyword for specifying date constants in Oracle.)

Answer (score 5):

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NUM, ITEM_NUM, DATE)
VALUES ('11','19', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2001','DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

use this code as you used wrong quote type

Answer (score 3):

It's almost certainly because you're using the wrong quote types, something that often happens when you cut'n'paste text from a word processor.

Your example has "angled" quotes rather than the correct `'` variant, meaning that either that's the *actual* problem, or that you've transcribed it incorrectly which leads me to think you're not matching quotes correctly.

This is what you *should* have:

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (PRODUCT_NUM, ITEM_NUM, DATE)
    VALUES ('11','19', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2001','DD-MON-YYYY'));
```

Comment: oh! I am new to OSX. thank you very much! Acthaully, I was using OSX textEdit to write the commands. TextEdit automatically put "angled" quotes.Missing Windows Notepad :-"

Comment: @user3315642, that's usually caused by people copying out of a word processor where at least changing quotes may make sense. It makes absolutely _zero_ sense in a text editor. In this case, it's simply because it's _not_ a text editor despite the name - they have chosen a bad name for a product that's touted as a word processor.

Answer (score 2):

use a normal quote, your quote seems to be odd.